# Adding a new action to a restful resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, controller, routes, action

I need to sort of add a secondary show action to my Photos controller. I have named it fullscreen.

My show action shows a photo in the center of the page and the fullscreen action will take over the page and show the photo as large as it can be.

How would I set this up in my router and what would the link be like on the image on the view that rendered for the Photo Show action?

Just wondering how all this fits together?

Here is my Photo Controller:

```
class Gallery::PhotosController < Gallery::GalleryController

   def index
      @photos = Photo.all
   end

   def show
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
      @album = Album.where(id: @photo.album_id).first
      @first_of_album = Photo.where(album_id: @album.id).first
      @last_of_album = Photo.where(album_id: @album.id).last

      respond_to do |format|
         format.html

         format.js
      end
   end

   def fullscreen
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
      @album = Album.where(id: @photo.album_id).first
      @first_of_album = Photo.where(album_id: @album.id).first
      @last_of_album = Photo.where(album_id: @album.id).last
   end

end
```

and my router for this part:

```
   namespace :gallery do
      resources :collections, only: [:index, :show] do
         resources :albums, only: [:index, :show] do
            resources :photos, only: :show
         end
      end
   end
```

I take it I can't use a link helper as Rails won;t have generated one without an applicable route but i'm not sure how to erm 'plumb' this in at the router side?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer so my help diesnt cost me points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
resources :photos, only: :show do
  member do
    get :fullscreen
  end
end
```

[Here is the relevant doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Comment: Code+ doc, should I commit it myself?

Comment: Thankyou. This worked nicely and makes sense. I take it I would use a collection route for something that needs to be available for a group of items?